# Storyboard is applied to many elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two rectangles in my WPF application. I want to play an animation when I click on an element. The animation should be applied to only the clicked rectangle. With the code below, when I click on a rectangle, all the shapes get animated.

What should I do??

```
Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExecutionInitialization" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC0FBBA"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0FA000" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0FA000"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonDown1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rec1">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.17"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.32"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0.5"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.56"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </ResourceDictionary>


</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Rectangle MouseDown="rec1_MouseDown" Name="rec1" Fill="{StaticResource ExecutionInitialization}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="85.075" Margin="24.358,27.731,0,0" Stroke="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156.717"/>

    <Rectangle MouseDown="rec2_MouseDown" Name="rec2" Fill="{StaticResource ExecutionInitialization}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="113.433" Margin="246.746,141.164,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="211.941"/>

</Grid>
```

and the c#

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    animation = TryFindResource("OnMouseLeftButtonDown1") as Storyboard;
}

private void rec1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    animation.Begin();
}

private void rec2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `x:Shared` attribute to `false` on your LinearGradientBrush resource. Then each Rectangle's Fill property gets its own copy of the Brush assigned.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExecutionInitialization" x:Shared="false"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    ...
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

In order to run the animation independently on different Rectangles, you would also have to remove the `Storyboard.TargetName`, and start the Storybord with the target control as parameter:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = TryFindResource("OnMouseLeftButtonDown1") as Storyboard;
    storyboard.Begin((FrameworkElement)sender);
}
```

You might then also use the same event handler for all such Rectangles:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rec1" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" .../>
<Rectangle x:Name="rec2" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" .../>
```